# Upload files to OneDrive from outlook desktop client using outlook AddIn without user interaction

Tags: outlook, add-in, onedrive

I am developing an Outlook Add-In, that will work in Office365 for both Web version and Desktop client and will able to upload files attached with the email to One-drive. Is it possible to authenticate and upload the files without user interaction(i.e. like opening popup, and providing user id and password etc).

Thanking all for your suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible.
What you have to do is :

1) create **OutlookAddin** solution with help of visual studio template.

2) It will add two projects in that solution **OutlookAddin** and **OutlookAddinWeb**.

3) Here **OutlookAddinWeb** is simple asp.net project that you have to covert into **MVC Web API** or you can add in new **MVC Web API** project after removing the existing **OutlookAddinWeb**.

4) Now,You can **Microsoft Graph Client** dll to use graph api functionalities to upload file in One Drive.

**Note** : The important thing you shouldn't forget about implementing authentication using **OWIN API** that is providing **single sign-on** as it is your main concern here

samples: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/code-samples

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, we have resolved that already.